# How to make cpanel stop disable nginx ? Any expert with cpanel or a really skillful person

Tags: cpanel

our site runs nginx with 50,000 daily visitors, together with cpanel, however these days cpanel keep stopping nginx for no reason and our site shows " connection was reset " whenever cpanel stopping nginx, how can we prevent cpanel from stopping nginx ? we can't monitor our site every 5 minutes to restart nginx everytime it stop it or to add cron job to start nginx automatically, although its added inside now, but we want the cpanel that is installed on our server to not stop nginx that is running in our server. Please help us with this, we are losing revenue because everytime cpanel stop the nginx is running on our server and the downtime is long when we are away :(

basically I want to either disable httpd for good so it doesn't start again and disable my nginx, or somehow stop cpanel from stopping my nginx and start other stuffs. i tried to go the cpanel forum and leave a question on this because trying to register on the forum is difficult, it keep saying capcha incorrect when i type in the correct captha :(